# C# Constructor syntax explanation needed

Tags: c#, constructor

Can someone please explain the following constructor syntax to me. I haven't come across it before and noticed it in a colleagues code.

```
public Service () : this (Service.DoStuff(), DoMoreStuff())
{ }
```

Comment: It runs another constructor passing there 2 results from 2 static methods

Comment: This is called constructor-chaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It chains to another constructor in the same class. Basically any constructor can *either* chain to another constructor in the same class using `: this (...)`, *or* to a constructor in the base class using `: base(...)`. If you don't have either, it's equivalent to `: base()`.

The chained constructor is executed *after* instance variable initializers have been executed, but *before* the body of the constructor.

See [my article on constructor chaining](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/constructors.html) or the [MSDN topic on C# constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for more information.

As an example, consider this code:

```
using System;

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(string x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class constructor");
        Console.WriteLine("x={0}, y={1}", x, y);
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Chains to the 1-parameter constructor
    public DerivedClass() : this("Foo")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived class parameterless");
    }

    public DerivedClass(string text) : base(text, text.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived class with parameter");
    }

}

static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new DerivedClass();
    } 
}
```

The `Main` method calls the parameterless constructor in `DerivedClass`. That chains to the one-parameter constructor in `DerivedClass`, which then chains to the two-parameter constructor in `BaseClass`. When that base constructor completes, the one-parameter constructor in `DerivedClass` continues, then when *that* finishes, the original parameterless constructor continues. So the output is:

```
Base class constructor
x=Foo, y=3
Derived class with parameter
Derived class parameterless
```

Comment: Thanks. So does that syntax mean that this constructor chains to the default constructor for this class and effectively extends it? Thanks for the links. Wil check them out at lunch.

Comment: @CSharpened: No, this constructor *replaces* a default constructor. It chains to a constructor with two parameters. See my example.

Comment: Ok thanks again. I will read into it now that I know the term for it and have the articles etc.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, there must a a second constructor which will accept two parameters - the return values of `Service.DoStuff()` and `DoMoreStuff()`. These two methods must be static methods.

Comment: Just for a little clarification before I read up does the syntax effectively run the call to the base class constructor (or first link in the chain) first and then follow the chain back up and call each constructor in turn until the chain ends?

Comment: It will call the second constructor on your class first, and then see if this second constructor has a base call - if not, it will call base().